# Сессия закрывается после закрывания брузера

Tags: php, сессия

Здраствуйте! У меня появилась проблема: у меня сессия закрывается после закрытия браузера. Почему?. Если я закрываю вкладку с страницей где установлена сессия, сессия не завершается, но если я закрою браузер и заново зайду на ту страницу, у меня сессия закроется.

index.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once 'includes/config.php';
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title><?php echo $config['title']; ?></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
  require_once 'includes/connection.php';
  require_once 'includes/header.php';
?>

<section>
  <div class="container">

      <?php require_once 'includes/slider.php'; ?>

      <br /> <br />

      <div class="slider__films">
        <input checked type="radio" name="respond" id="main">
        <article id="slider__films">
          <input checked type="radio" name="respond__slide" id="film__switch1">
          <input type="radio" name="respond__slide" id="film__switch2">
          <input type="radio" name="respond__slide" id="film__switch3">
          <input type="radio" name="respond__slide" id="film__switch4">
          <input type="radio" name="respond__slide" id="film__switch5">
      <div id="films__slides">
        <div id="films__overflow">
          <div class="films__image">
            <article class="article">
              <div style="display: contents;">
                <?php
                  $db = new DB();
                  $db->requestPrepareFetchAll("SELECT film_name, film_small_img FROM new_film");
                ?>
                <?php foreach ($stmt as $row): ?>
                  <a href="films/<?php echo $row['film_name']; ?>.php">
                    <img src="<?php echo $row['film_small_img']; ?>" alt="" style="width: 100px;">
                    <p><?php echo $row['film_name']; ?></p>
                  </a>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="films__controls">
        <label for="film__switch1"></label>
        <label for="film__switch2"></label>
        <label for="film__switch3"></label>
        <label for="film__switch4"></label>
        <label for="film__switch5"></label>
      </div>
      <div id="films__active">
        <label for="film__switch1"></label>
        <label for="film__switch2"></label>
        <label for="film__switch3"></label>
        <label for="film__switch4"></label>
        <label for="film__switch5"></label>
      </div>
      </article>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

header.php

```
<?php
        require_once "config.php";
     ?>

     <header>
       <div class="headerflex">
         <a href="../index.php" class="logo"><?php echo $config['title']; ?></a>

         <div class="opencategory">
           <img src="../img/movie-clapper-open.svg" alt="" class="menuimg" onclick="openMenu()">
           <img src="../img/cancel-cross.svg" alt="" class="cancelcross" onclick="closeMenu()">
           <a href="#" class="category">Категории кино</a>
             <ul class="headercategory">
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Фильмы</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Сериалы</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Аниме</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Комедии</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Боёвики</a>
               </li>
             </ul>
         </div>

         <a href="#"><img src="../img/search.svg" class="searchimg" onclick="openSearchInput()"></a>
         <input type="search" class="search" placeholder="Поиск по сайту">

         <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user'])): ?>
           <a href="../includes/admin.php"><img src="../img/avatar.svg" class="avatar"></a>
         <?php else: ?>
           <a href="../includes/signin.php" class="acclink">Войти</a>
           <a href="../includes/signup.php" class="acclink">Зарегистрироваться</a>
        <?php endif; ?>

         <a href="#"><img src="../img/telegram.svg" alt="" class="telegram"></a>
       </div>
     </header>
```

Так код выгладить при авторизации[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так код выгладить при авторизации но после перезагрузки браузера[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В php.ini

```
session.cookie_lifetime = 2678400
session.gc_maxlifetime = 2678400
```

Что делать?

Comment: По моему это стандартное поведение. Хотите хранить информацию дольше, сохраняйте в куки

Comment: Куки не безопасно

Comment: Приходится чем-то жертвовать

Comment: Один из вариантов - посмотрите, как сделана авторизация в популярных фреймворках (laravel, yii и т.д.).

Comment: Судя по документации установка этих опций в php.ini должна делать сессию зависящей только от времени, но не от закрытия браузера. Ощущение, что настройки вашего скрипта берутся не из того php.ini, который вы правите. Проверьте в браузере время жизни сессионной куки (в хроме: режим разработчика -> application ->cookies)

Comment: Пишет N/A почему то

Answer (score 3):

Если что, сессии работают тоже через куки, сделать безопасными куки - ничего сложного.

Например пользователь авторизовался, вы записываете в сессию его данные и генерируете ключ, этот ключ записываем в бд и те данные которые у нас в сессии (обычно это какие-то якоря, типа ид пользователя и чтоб по нему потом можно было загрузить инфу). В куках храним этот ключ (сгенерированный).

Пользователь закрыл браузер, зашел на сайт: сессия сбилась, но есть кука с ключом. По этому ключу вы делаете запрос к БД на получение данных с проверкой. Если ип, агент и прочие параметры совпадают, то ключ считаем валидным и записываем в сессию рабочие данные обратно (такой подход позволяет не делать запросы к бд каждый раз).

Если проверка не удалась - удаляем куку у агента и из бд (для безопасности)...

Answer (score 1):

Сессии прекращают своё существование после закрытия браузера, поэтому информацию хранят в cookies. Можно записать логин в куки при удачной авторизации и орудовать с помощью него. Если Вы беспокоитесь о безопасности - то в таком случае вам нужно сделать несколько проверок. В случае, если вы хотите использовать исключительно сессии, то session_cache_limiter, session_cache_expire ( и session.gc_maxlifetime в .htaccess ) Вам  в помощь.